# How to generate clean PayPal checkout from a Buy Now button?

Tags: paypal

My experience with PayPal is that yes, they will process credit cards, but only after they pressure my customer to use their PayPal account, instead,  if they have one, and to sign up for a PayPal account if they don't have one. And the PayPal checkout is, in general, full of PayPal icons.

But I came across a BUY NOW button on a Weebly page (www.furniture1234.weebly.com) where the checkout, when you click the Buy Now for the widget product, is very clean, asking simply for credit card information without a peep about PayPal, and no PayPal icons anywhere.

Does anyone know how this was done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must have been [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#wpp).  That's the only way to integrate credit cards directly without any redirection or iframe or anything like that.

Part of the Pro agreement, though, is that you'll also include [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/#ec) as an option on your site.  This way users could simply choose credit card or PayPal, and if they choose CC it'll be direct with no redirection or PayPal logos (or however you design that into your site).  If they choose PayPal it would redirect like they'd expect so they can sign in and pay.

If you don't include Express Checkout they'll eventually warn you, and then jack up your fees a little bit on your Pro transactions.

It's really recommended to include PayPal as an option anyway because conversion rates are proven to rise when you do.

Comment: Thanks Andrew but it's definitely not Payments Pro. I generated the page with a free Weebly account and just a Business account at PayPal. Plus, Weebly's documentation says to set up an online store "you need a  Paypal Business/Premier account."  I think Payments Pro is something like $30/mo.  There's nothing like that going on here. I'm wondering if Weebly's 12 million customers convinced PayPal to give them a special API.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: You should be able to go to www.furniture1234.weebly.com and click the Buy Now box below the cat eye image to see what I'm seeing.

Comment: Solved it!  The Weebly page was configured to use "Stripe" as the payment processor, not PayPal. 'Sorry for the confusion. Configured to use PayPal it looks just like I would expect.